# Enable both paypal standard and paypal express checkout payment methods in magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to enable both paypal standard and paypal express checkout but `Magento` 1.7.0.2 seems to only allow 1 paypal payment method to be enabled in the admin at a time.

I did a hack by enabling paypal express checkout then in `Paypal/Model/Standard.php` made `isAvailable()` to always return true.  This makes paypal standard always available in checkout.

Customers can checkout fine, but it seems like it doesn't update `magento` with the details. I tried resending `ipn` but the order with paypal standard still doesn't update.  After disabling express checkout and enabling paypal standard in the admin then resending `ipn` it updated.

How should I go about successfully enabling 2 paypal payment methods?

Edit: I managed to make the ipn work by setting `payment/paypal_standard/active` to 1 in `core_config_data` in the database, then flushing the caches.

Comment: use website payments pro or something similar. They turned on express checkout also.